# How can i remove a selected item from asyncstorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm making a simple movie watchlist application.
I use asyncstorage to save the selected movies.
I want to remove the movie the user has selected in the watchlist section. Right now I am trying this code:

```
    removeItemValue= async (item, index) => {
    let value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('movies');
    value1 =JSON.parse(value1);
    console.log("value1"+value)
    //value = item.splice(index,1)
    if (value1 !== null){
        //var index = value.indexOf(x => x.Title === item.Title);
        if (index > -1){
        value1.splice(index, 1);
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('movies');
        
        AsyncStorage.setItem('movies',JSON.stringify(value)); 
        
    }
    }       
    
}
```

But this isn't working.
Can you tell me where is wrong?

Also my click part:
[image]

Comment: Your storage can only hold string values. `AsyncStorage.getItem` if successful, will resolve to a string. You need to deserialize the string using `JSON.parse()`. You can only do this if you have stored the data correctly (ie: as a JSON formatted string), this can be done using `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I added the function you said and updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
removeItemValue = async(index) => { // don't need item here
  // avoid mutations, create new variables
  const rawValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('movies');
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.parse(rawValue) || []; // avoid undefined or null
    const finalValue = [...jsonValue.slice(0, index), ...jsonValue.slice(index + 1)];
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('movies', JSON.stringify(finalValue)); // add await here
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Parsing failed', e)
  }
}
```

And remove using `() => this.removeItemValue(index)`

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try this

```js
var moviesArray = [{title:'A1'},{title:'A2'},{title:'A3'},{title:'A4'},{title:'A5'},{title:'A6'},{title:'A7'},]

removeSelectedMovie=(name)=>{
return moviesArray.filter(item=>item.title.toLowerCase() !== name.toLowerCase())
}

//removeSelectedMovie(MovieName here and its will return a //new array excluded selected movie name)
console.log(removeSelectedMovie('a1'))
console.log(removeSelectedMovie('a3'))
console.log(removeSelectedMovie('a4'))
console.log(removeSelectedMovie('a7'))
```